# Find all pair(s) of positive integer $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{a^2}{2ab^2 -b^3+1}$ is also positive integer too?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Another number theory problem.

I can find the small value of $b$ such that 0,1,2.

But, I cannot find the upper limit of $b$, such that the value of $b$ is limited.

How can I find the solution $(a,b)$ from this problem?

Thanks

Comment: If $b$ is even, then $a = b/2$ always works...

Comment: also $b \leq 2a$ for the expression to be positive.

Comment: This is IMO 2003 problem. You can check the solutions on [AOPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=262&sid=5e2b1a81372fb450e05fd83c4b9d415f#p262)

Comment: And how to be with the decisions of which are determined by the equations Pell?

Comment: Use so-called "Vieta jumping", i.e. [descent by reflection on integer points of a conic.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/38528/242)

Comment: How can we related this form with Pell equations or 'Vieta Jumping'? Are they related? I just heard the word 'Vieta jumping' today. Thanks

Comment: This does two different methods.